# How can I stop Thunderbird adding strange characters?

Tags: thunderbird

I use Thunderbird 24.0 under Ubuntu 11.04.

When I forward a message the character Â is added before an 's.

So Claire's becomes ClaireÂ's.

Also the spacing between paragraphs disappears.

It makes the forwarded e-mail look messy and badly written.

How can I correct this?

Comment: "Ubuntu 11.04" <-- Why? This is really old and end-of-life. This indicates that you're running a Thunderbid from a 3rd party software source, because version 24 has never been shipped with 11.04. So, either you mistyped the Ubuntu version or you left out an important part in your question. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

When this occurs, try switching the encoding of the outgoing e-mail to UTF-8. Select menu *Tools / Character Encoding*, then pick UTF-8.

If this helps, consider setting UTF-8 as the default character encoding for outgoing mail. Select menu *Edit / Preferences / Advanced* and set the default encoding for outgoing mail.

Comment: As wierd as this may seem, I have neither Tools / Character not Preferences / Advanced / encoding menus.  I was looking for the encoding before I posted but could not find it.

Comment: @user203748 Are you sure you're using Thunderbird then? Or aren't you able to locate the menu which is hidden behind a small button in the top right corner?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to look in Tools/Options/Display/Formatting tab - advanced, make sure both out going and incoming are set to utf-8 especially if you use 'Edit as New' a lot...

Comment: What version of Tb, on what platform (OS) are you using ?  To access character encoding you need to go to `Edit > Preferences > Display > Formatting`. This is for an up-to date Tb 38.3 on Ubuntu 14.04.3. Please edit yr answer with that information.